# r increment column value based on another column value

Tags: r

I have a datatable `x` like this

```
+----+---------------+-------+
| id |      arg      | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1 | New Day       | NA    |
|  2 | Eat breakfast | 3     |
|  3 | Bike          | 45    |
|  4 | New Day       | 0     |
|  5 | Get coffee    | 1     |
|  6 | Exercise      | 15    |
|  7 | Get beer      | NA    |
|  8 | New Day       |       |
|  9 | Pet cat       |       |
+----+---------------+-------+
```

I would like to add an incrementing column for every day to get something like this

```
+----+---------------+-------+-----+
| id |      arg      | value | day |
+----+---------------+-------+-----+
|  1 | New Day       | NA    |   1 |
|  2 | Eat breakfast | 3     |   1 |
|  3 | Bike          | 45    |   1 |
|  4 | New Day       | 0     |   2 |
|  5 | Get coffee    | 1     |   2 |
|  6 | Exercise      | 15    |   2 |
|  7 | Get beer      | NA    |   2 |
|  8 | New Day       |       |   3 |
|  9 | Pet cat       |       |   3 |
+----+---------------+-------+-----+
```

I have tried this without much success

```
x$day <-0
x<-within(x, day<-ifelse(arg == "New day", day+1, day))
```

Comment: `cumsum(arg == "New day")`

Comment: @A.Webb Many tanks. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @A.Webb

```
cumsum(arg == "New day")
```